# Switch Current and Voltage Ratings

Tags: current, switches, datasheet, switching, contact

On a datasheet for a single pole, multiple contact switch, I see that there are a few contact ratings: non-switching (50VDC, 100mA), switching (5VDC, 100mA) and minimum (20mVDC, 1uA). What are these different specs describing?

If I anticipate my system to draw 3VDC at around 100mA (300mW), am I good to use this switch since it is rated for 500mW or must I obey the current and voltage specs independent of each other?

Comment: _"If I anticipate my system to draw 3VDC at around 100mA (300mW), am I good to use this switch since it is rated for 500mW ... ?"_ - By that reasoning, the switch should also be usable for 0.01V 50A (500mW), or 1000V 0.5mA (500mW). Guess what? It ain't ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non switching:  You can apply 50VDC with a load current of 100mA as long as you don't change the state of the switch.

Switching: You can switch the load on and off all day with an applied voltage of 5VDC and a load current of 100mA.

Minimum:  The applied voltage should exceed 20mVDC and the load current should be at least 1uA in order to guarantee reliable switching.

With an applied voltage of 3VDC and a load current of 100mA you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes none of the specs should violated. They are inclusive.

- The max voltage is due small contact separation for non-switching and small reactive loads reduce the operting voltage to 5V.
- the min current is minor oxidation
- the max current is to minimize contact heating.

These low specs also imply no switching large capacitive or inductive (reactive) loads.

Your application  appears to be betwwn these limits.